# How to change texts on VueJS

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to be able to change the texts in an animation like the person did on his own website: https://mauri870.github.io/#/

However, I don't understand how he did it on his template.
I was wondering if there's more straight forward way.

My website is also built in VueJS

I have tried:

In the script tag:

```
  methods: {
    formOpen() {
      //...
    },
    openPdf() {
      //....
    },
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            changingText('.changing-text',['Hi I am!', 'How are you doing']);
        },1000);
    });
  }
};
```

My Tag:

```
//...    
<div class='changing-text'> </div>
//...
```

I've also added jQuery into this component as well as the application

Comment: https://eduardostuart.github.io/vue-typewriter/dist/

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: In this example he used **typed.js** https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/